# Two way binding showing in Angular5 showing TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5

I am making a form in Angular5 using firebase in backend for my learning purpose. My two way binding is not working. It is giving me below error on console.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null
```

Here is my template:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(f.value)">        
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title</label>

            <input #title="ngModel" 
            [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-control" required>
            <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1" *ngIf="title.touched && title.invalid">
              Title is required.
            </div>
          </div>
    <!-- other input fields here -->
    </form>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Product } from './../../models/product';
import { CategoryService } from './../../category.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../../product.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
  categories$;
  product: any = {};

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private categoryService: CategoryService,
    private productService: ProductService) {
    this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (id) {
      this.productService.get(id)
        .take(1).subscribe(p => this.product = p);
      // this is coming empty
      console.log(this.product);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  save(product) {
    this.productService.create(product);
    this.router.navigate(['/admin/products']);
  }

}
```

And here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  create(product) {
    return this.db.list('/products').push(product);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().map(categories => {
      return categories.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
  }

  get(productId) {
       return this.db.object('/products' + productId).valueChanges();
    }
}
```

Please guide me what's wrong with my code. I'm new to angular. I'm not able to solve it. Please help.

Comment: It's because product is not set yet when binding occurs. Try the ? operator `[(ngModel)]="product?.title"` or ngIf :  `<input *ngIf="product"`

Comment: I think it's because of the url. `'/products' + productId` should be `'/products/' + productId` right?

Comment: @Orlandster thanks. That was the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for the exception is because product property is not defined when dom is initializing.

there're two options two bypass the problem:

`*ngif` the whole form.

use `?` operator like this:

`<input #title="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="product.title" name="title" id="title" type="text"`...